# Where is general.phrase.written-by-on coming from in bolt record template?

Tags: twig, bolt-cms

I was just going through the bolt template for _recordfooter , in the default theme and came across the following liens of code:

```
{{ __('general.phrase.written-by-on', {
        '%name%': record.user.displayname|default(__('Unknown')),
        '%date%': record.datepublish|localedatetime("%A %B %e, %Y")
    }) }}
```

I am not quite understanding what the above line of code is really doing and most of all i am not understanding what the usage of the double underline function and also what exactly is `'general.phrase.written-by-on'` and where is it coming from ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are keyword in the base translation file, in the loacle specific directory under `vendor/bolt/bolt/app/resources/translations/`

Comment: can u explain what exact does the functin __ do ?? i mean elaborate a bit more. Thanks

Comment: It is just a shortcut function to the translation service. The string you mention above, `general.phrase.written-by-on` in the English translation file has the base value of `"Written by <em>%name%</em> on %date%"`, so the array value in the second parameter is just a list of strings that get replaced with dynamic values.